# Boostrap center inline inputs with no space between them

Tags: html, css

I **removed** the **spacing between multiple input fields** and the submit button using *float:left*.

But I dont know how to keep this hole block centered on the page.

[image]

Here is a Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/43/

And the code:

```css
  .form-control {

    float: left;

    border-radius: 0px;

  }

  .btn {

    float: left;

    border-radius: 0px;

  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12" style="margin-left:0px;padding-right:0px;margin-top:50px;padding-left:0px; height:100vh;">

  <div style="background-color:white;width:100%;height:100%;">

    <div style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:50px;padding-top:30px;">

      <form>
        <div class=form-inline style='text-align:center;'>
          <select name="Form1" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form1</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <select name="Form2" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form2</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <select name="Form3" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form3</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

        </div>


      </form>


    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the floats and use flexbox instead.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9qs10404/1/)

```
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12" style="margin-left:0px;padding-right:0px;margin-top:50px;padding-left:0px; height:100vh;">

  <div style="background-color:white;width:100%;height:100%;">

    <div style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:50px;padding-top:30px;">

      <form>
        <div class=form-inline style='text-align:center;'>
          <select name="Form1" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form1</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <select name="Form2" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form2</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <select name="Form3" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Form3</option>
            <option value="1">Option2</option>
            <option value="2">Option3</option>
          </select>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

        </div>


      </form>


    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Otherwise you will have to review [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: the problem is that it is the only way I found te remove the space between the input fields.

Comment: Ok the flexbox is great. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Change:

```
<div style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:50px;padding-top:30px;">
```

to

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto; padding-top: 30px; width: 427px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to have all your `.js` files or CDN(s) at the bottom of your HTML before the closing body tag.

You want to render your `.js` scripts last to help with your asset pipeline.